# Copy Sheet to Google Doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy a table from Google Sheet that includes pictures into a Google doc. 
So far I managed to accomplish several things, but not the result that I need.

Source Google Sheet  - table with pictures, filled by `Importrange` formula from another Google sheet.

1. Copying via `appendTable` does not copy pictures
2. I managed to export table to a pdf blob, but couldn't convert it to a regular Google doc then.

Any help appreciated.

```
function printDocument() {

  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var spreadsheetId=source.getId();
  var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName('Printable Shooting Plan');
  var sheetId = sourcesheet.getSheetId();
  var current_lastrow = getLastPopulatedRow(sourcesheet);
  var srcData = sourcesheet.getRange('A1:G'+current_lastrow).getValues();


  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(source.getId()).getParents();
  if (parents.hasNext()) {
    var folder = parents.next();
  }
  else {
    folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  }

  var doc = DocumentApp.create("Shooting Plan");
  var body = doc.getBody();

  body.insertParagraph(0, 'Shooting Plan').setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1).setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

  table = body.appendTable(srcData);
  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);

  // Copy doc to the directory we want it to be in. Delete it from root.
  var docFile = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
  folder.addFile(docFile);
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(docFile);   
}

function onOpen() {
  var submenu = [{name:"Save Doc", functionName:"printDocument"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('Export', submenu);  
}


function getLastPopulatedRow(sheet) {
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = data.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
      if (data[i][j]) return i+1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the Spreadsheet including the sample input values and the Document including the sample output you expect? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: @Tanaike 
I simplified my script. Here it is. 
The goal is to copy images that are inserted via Insert > Image from Google Sheet to Google text Doc https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Mf1F6uVq8rBIXx6LUfBAtpmbKGvJpESG?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet and Document. From the samples, I think that the reason of your issue is due to the current specification of Google side. In your Spreadsheet, the image is put in the cells. In this case, in the current stage, the images in the cells cannot be retrieved. By this, the images cannot be included in the table in Google Document. For example, the image is put using the URL like `=IMAGE(URL)`, the image can be retrieved from the URL.

Comment: I have another version of that script that uses the images' URLs and it works, but the employees complain that they need just to copy and paste pictures, not put them into a folder and get url for any one of them. Looking for some compromise. Thanks for your input!